# Why does any change in this sbt codeblock lead to a type error?

Tags: scala, sbt, typesafe-activator

I have a build.sbt file in a sub project that contains this code block:

```
stopMySql := {
  val log = streams.value.log
  val pid = pidFileMysql.value
  if(pid.exists) {
    val id = IO read pid
    IO delete pid
    log.info(s"Trying to stop $id")
    Process(Seq("docker", "stop", id)) !! log
  } else {
    log.warn("No running mysql container found")
  }
}
```

If I touch any character in this block my build fails with this error:

```
/home/xxxx/git/xxxxx/xxxxxxx/build.sbt:80: error: value value is not a member of sbt.SettingKey
  val pid = pidFileMysql.value
                         ^
[error] Type error in expression
```

For example if i replace this line:

```
log.warn("No running mysql container found")
```

with this line (uppercase M in mysql):

```
log.warn("No running Mysql container found")
```

I can add lines outside the code block without breaking the build. What is going on there? Is this code block somehow magically signed by sbt and it doesn't allow changes?

I'm using activator 1.2.10 to launch the build.

**Edit: Additional Information asked for in the comments:**

here is a gist to the whole file:
https://gist.github.com/pumpadump/e256dc9da264469e48ab

it is referenced from the main project with this code:

```
lazy val mysql = (project in file("xxxxxxx"))
  .enablePlugins(SlickCodeGenMySql)
  .settings(commonSettings: _*)
  .settings(
    libraryDependencies ++= akkaDependencies ++ testDependencies ++ databaseDependencies
  ).dependsOn(testkit % "test")
```

The goal of this sub-project is to set-up a test db in a docker container for running tests. I want to change the stopMysql codeblock to add additional docker commands for cleaning up afterwards.

Comment: Please publish your full sources / build. Either here or via gist. Otherwise, analysis becomes tedious .

Comment: Have you tried to perform 'sbt clean' before compile? just asking

Comment: The `value` member is added by an implicit and then rewritten by a macro. We don't even see the type of `pidFileMysql` to know what implicit is used; so more info is needed to debug it.